# Authorize Resource with Policy doesn't work on destroy() actions

Tags: laravel

I am using `$this->authorizeResource(Project::class, 'project');` and using a Project resourceful controller setup with an API auth. `dd()` on every policy function works, but not on `delete()`.

My equivalent record removal function in `ProjectController` is called `destroy`. It's very weird. Somehow, the policy method for delete isn't triggered. And I don't know why. It is kind of making me pull my hair.

The response is always this `{"status":403,"success":false,"error":{"code":"unauthorized","message":null}}`

Comment: Perhaps you have a Middleware or a Request which is restricting the action?

Comment: Why on `delete` specifically. It works fine on other policy methods like `get` etc

Comment: I can't help you more without seeing your code. Afaik, based on your question, the policy should work.

Comment: Here's my Route resource `Route::resource('projects', 'Project\ProjectController');`. It never reaches the `dd()` I have placed on `destroy` while this is in the constructor: `$this->authorizeResource(Project::class, 'p...`

Comment: Does it reaches `delete()` method in your policy?

Comment: Not at all. I did a manual policy register in Service provider and it works..weird

Answer (score 0):

Just change destroy method from this:

`public function destroy($id)`

to this:

`public function destroy(User $user)`

It works for me :)